# jQuery auto refresh - abort the page load when click a button

Tags: jquery, onclick, settimeout, abort

I have a dashboard which has a div contains dashboard contents. And that is refreshing itself from local database every 10 secs. (And there is another function for clock). This is my code:

```
setTimeout('sensorcells_load()', 10000);
function sensorcells_load()
{
    jQuery('#sensorcells').load('dashboard_content.php');
    setTimeout('sensorcells_load()', 10000);
    clock();        
}
```

My problem is, when I click a button in dashboard, that sometimes takes time to get the detail page. I guess that is because I need to wait for the .load('dashboard_content.php'). How can I stop the page loading when I click any details button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `window.onbeforeunload` with a global `.ajax()` function and `.abort()` .

```
var loadTimeout = setTimeout('sensorcellsLoad()', 3000);
function sensorcellsLoad(){
    window.ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'dashboard_content.php',
        success: function(data) {
         jQuery('#sensorcells').html(data);
         loadTimeout = setTimeout('sensorcellsLoad()', 3000); 
        }
    });
    clock();
}


window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    clearTimeout(loadTimeout); 
    window.ajaxRequest.abort();
};
```

This will always stop your timeout before unloading the current page, no matter how you unload it.

Also, adding a global varible like the following might be good practice:

```
var pageIsBeingRefreshed = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    pageIsBeingRefreshed = true;
};
```

This would make it possible to filter if an ajax error occured because of an actual error or the entire page reloading.

```
if (pageIsBeingRefreshed) {
    return;
} else {
    //Do some actual error handling.
}
```

Update:
I've modified the original code to make use of global window objects for the ajax handling.

JSFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/cnoL26ve/1/

Comment: Thanks Magnus. If we stop setTimeout, would it stop the page loading which already has been started? Because my problem is, it takes time to load data from database to dashboard (it takes 3-5 secs). I need to stop loading from database.

Comment: `clearTimeout` will not stop an ajax call that is already being performed.
But using `.abort()` will.
I'll update my post with this code.

Comment: I've modified the code to use `.ajax()` and `.abort()` instead of `.load()`.

Comment: I had error the line `var window.ajaxRequest = $.ajax({`. I delete `window` and tried. Page is loading in first load. But that is not refreshing every 10 secs :(

Comment: I've just updated the code again, try it now.
There shouldn't have been a `var` before the `window,ajaxRequest = ...`.
I've made a JSFiddle to show the code in action (The result not very pretty there though due to limitations in test-pages to call :) ), and i've also made use of setInterval rather than setTimeout since you're calling the same code over and over any way.

Comment: Your last updated code does not refresh again :( I remove `var` from your previous code as you told, That is refreshing now. But unfortunately, It is still waiting for loading :( Is that possible to have problem `window.onbeforeunload = function () {` part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87904/discussion-between-magnus-svensson-and-cvdogan).

Answer (score 0):

Use [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) like,

```
var t=setTimeout('sensorcells_load()', 10000);
function sensorcells_load()
{
    jQuery('#sensorcells').load('dashboard_content.php');
    t = setTimeout('sensorcells_load()', 10000);
    clock();        
}
// let your button id is stopLoading
$('#stopLoading').on('click',function(){
   clearTimeout(t);
});
```

Update: If you want the time our after your database operations are performed then use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load) callback like,

```
setTimeout('sensorcells_load()', 10000);
function sensorcells_load()
{
    jQuery('#sensorcells').load('dashboard_content.php',function(){
        setTimeout('sensorcells_load()', 10000); // wait for response then again load after 10 seconds
    });        
    clock();        
}
```

Comment: I asked the same question to Magnus. If we stop setTimeout, would it stop the page loading which already has been started? Because my problem is, it takes time to load data from database to dashboard (it takes 3-5 secs). I need to stop loading from database.